# How to find values in an array that matches with other arrays value in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 2 collections in MongoDB:
User: favourite_tags: array[] and Event: title: string, tags: array[], so my question is: how can i find an event title that has at least 1 of the favourites tag of a user?

For example the user "A" has in his favourites tags rock, dance and food, the events with tags are: marathon (run, sport), eating contest (food, drink) and general rock band concert (music, rock).

Excpected result after the find are:
concert, eating contest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be done using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) (be sure to refer to the documentation matching your version of mongoDB).

In this answer, I used mongoDB v3.4.19

**Sample data**

```
db.getCollection('users').insert(
    {
        name: "bob",
        favourite_tags: ["rock", "dance", "food"]
    }
)
db.getCollection('events').insertMany([
    {
        title: "marathon",
        tags: ["run", "sport"]
    },
    {
        title: "eating contest",
        tags: ["food", "drink"]
    },
    {
        title: "general rock band concert",
        tags: ["music", "rock"]
    }
])
```

**Query for events that have at least 1 matching user (includes matched users in results)**:

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "tags",
            foreignField: "favourite_tags",
            as: "users"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            users: {
                $ne: []
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Results**:

```
    {
        "title" : "eating contest",
        "tags" : [ 
            "food", 
            "drink"
        ],
        "users" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "bob",
                "favourite_tags" : [ 
                    "rock", 
                    "dance", 
                    "food"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title" : "general rock band concert",
        "tags" : [ 
            "music", 
            "rock"
        ],
        "users" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "bob",
                "favourite_tags" : [ 
                    "rock", 
                    "dance", 
                    "food"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Query for users that matches them to events (includes events they matched with)**:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "events",
            localField: "favourite_tags",
            foreignField: "tags",
            as: "matchingEvents"
        }
    }
])
```

**Results**:

```
{
    "name" : "bob",
    "favourite_tags" : [ 
        "rock", 
        "dance", 
        "food"
    ],
    "matchingEvents" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "eating contest",
            "tags" : [ 
                "food", 
                "drink"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "general rock band concert",
            "tags" : [ 
                "music", 
                "rock"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @LorenzoMontini did this answer your question?